# I want the program to loop every time the sensor detects anything in 15cm

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, arduino-ultra-sonic

This is the code:

```
def check_ultra():
    global arduinoSerialData, y, i, x
    while True:
        if arduinoSerialData.inWaiting() > 1:
            myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
            myData = str(myData)
            myData = myData.replace("b'", '')
            myData = myData.replace("\\r\\n'", str(0))
            myData = myData.replace("\\r00.000", str(0))
            myData = myData.replace("\\r00.000", str(0))
            if "c" in myData:
                myData = myData.replace("c", str(0))

                if y == 1:
                    y = 3
                    if float(myData) > 15:
                        x = 0
                    return y, x
                else:
                    if float(myData) < 15 and float(myData) > 1:
                        y = 1
                        x = 0
                        return y, x
            elif "a" in myData:
                myData = myData.replace("a", str(0))
                if y == 2:
                    y = 3
                    if float(myData) > 15:
                        x = 0
                    return y, x
                else:
                    if float(myData) < 15 and float(myData) > 1:
                        y = 2
                        x = 0
                        return y, x
            else:
                y = 0
                return y


set_servo1_angle(0)
set_servo2_angle(90)
go_out_count = 0
m1 = 0
count = 3
y = 0
i = 0
x = 0
while y == None or y == 0 or x == 1:
    # i = 0
    # y = None
    check_ultra()
    if y == 1 and x == 0:
        print("1")
        sleep(2)
    elif y == 2 and x == 0:
        print('2')
        sleep(2)
```

What this currently does is it prints 1 every time sensor 1 is blocked, but then it ends the code. I want to make it such that every time I block a sensor, it prints the corresponding print statement, no matter how many times I block the sensor. I have tried adding many variables to help but they didnt work. How do I make the loop keep repeating?

Comment: So the final loop ends too soon? Looks to me like as soon as `y==1` and `x==0` the loop will print and then the while conditions will be all false, so the program exits. Make that final loop more like `while True:` if you want it to keep looping.

Comment: If I make it while true, it would just go on forever, even if the sensors are not triggered

Comment: The logic of what you want is not at all clear - please edit your question to explain what it is that you actually want to happen, being very specific and clear about the condition for whan the program should exit - and if it doesn’t exit it will have to loop or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer-most loop has the following condition: `y==None or y==0 or x==1`. The `if` statements in it are only going to print if all of those conditions are `False`. That means the loop is guaranteed to terminate on the first printout.

If you want the loop to keep going indefinitely, ignore everything and keep going. Replace the loop with

```
while True:
    check_ultra()
    ...
```

On an unrelated note, try to avoid globals. They may have unpredictable side effects when you set them in long-forgotten places, and generally make the code harder to maintain. Use arguments and return values instead.

For example:

```
def check_ultra(arduinoSerialData, x, y):
    while True:
        if arduinoSerialData.inWaiting() > 1:
            myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
            myData = str(myData)
            myData = myData.replace("b'", '')
            myData = myData.replace("\\r\\n'", str(0))
            myData = myData.replace("\\r00.000", str(0))
            myData = myData.replace("\\r00.000", str(0))
            if "c" in myData:
                myData = float(myData.replace("c", "0"))

                if y == 1:
                    if myData > 15:
                        return 0, 3
                    return x, 3
                elif 1 < myData < 15:
                        return 0, 1
                return x, y
            elif "a" in myData:
                myData = float(myData.replace("a", "0"))
                if y == 2:
                    if myData > 15:
                    return 0, 3
                elif 1 < myData < 15:
                    return 0, 2
                return x, y
            else:
                return x, 0
```

You would call it as

```
x, y = check_ultra(arduinoSerialData, x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

'break' statement ends the while loop, so try replacing it with 'pass', like this:

```
elif y == 2:
   print('2')
   pass
```

Comment: nope,tried it,didnt work.Thanks for the help though!